# Using a typedef set with custom comparator from another file - function has internal linkage but is not defined

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to typedef a set with a custom comparator and then use that set in another file but I'm running into some compilation errors. I've simplified the problem to these files.

### A.hpp

```
#ifndef A_HEADER
#define A_HEADER

#include <set>


struct Tuple {
    int i;
    char c;
};

auto cmp = [](const Tuple &a, const Tuple &b) { return a.i < b.i; };
typedef std::set<Tuple, decltype(cmp)> TupleSet;

TupleSet getTuples(void);

#endif
```

### A.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"

TupleSet getTuples(void) {
    TupleSet s(cmp);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        Tuple t = {i, 'a'};
        s.insert(t);
    }

    return s;
}
```

### B.hpp

```
#ifndef B_HEADER
#define B_HEADER

#include "A.hpp"

void foo(void);

#endif
```

### B.cpp

```
#include "B.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void foo(void) {
    TupleSet s = getTuples();
    for (const Tuple &t : s) {
        std::cout << "(" << t.i << ", " << t.c << ")\n";
    }
}

int main(void) {
    foo();
}
```

This is then compiled with `clang++ -c -o A.o A.cpp` and then `clang++ -o B B.cpp A.o` with the intention of creating an executable that prints those Tuples out. However, the error I get during compilation is

```
In file included from B.cpp:1:
In file included from ./B.hpp:4:
./A.hpp:15:10: warning: function 'getTuples' has internal linkage but is not defined [-Wundefined-internal]
TupleSet getTuples(void);
         ^
B.cpp:5:18: note: used here
    TupleSet s = getTuples();
                 ^
1 warning generated.
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/B-ec93ec.o: in function `foo()':
B.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `getTuples()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance.

Comment: Global variable `cmp` is defined in two translation units, in violation of the One Definition Rule (ODR).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Can you elaborate on this a bit more? I'm not quite folllowing

Comment: `decltype(cmp)` - the type of the lambda - is different in each translation unit. I suspect that's the one having internal linkage, and then so does everything using it; but I haven't looked up chapter and verse.

Comment: It's straightforward, really, Just having, say, `int x = 42;` in a header and including this header in two or more source files is ODR violation since it defines `x` more than once. `cmp` is no different.

Comment: I see - what's the solution to this then?

Comment: Define an honest `TupleComparator` class, and use that with the set. Don't try to get clever with lambdas.

Comment: Alright i'll give that a shot. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

The type of a lambda function is different for each use. Thus, the object `cmp` has two problems:

1. It is defined in more than one translation unit, violating the one defintion rule.
2. The typ of `cmp` is different in each translation unit.

As the compiler knows that a lambda function will have a different type in a different translation unit, it can deduce that any function using the type of the object `cmp` *must* be defined in the current translation unit. Thus, it concludes that `getTuples` must be defined in the current translation unit when it is used.

You probably want to define a comparison operator for your `Tuple`, e.g., using

```
bool operator< (Tuple const& t0, Tuple const& t1) { return t0.i < t1.i; }
```

As an aside, functions without parameters are written without parameters in C++, i.e., use `void f()`. Only if you intend your code to be also usable with C (which *may* be the case for headers) you may want to keep the `void`. However, your header uses, e.g., `std::set` which won't be available for C.

Comment: Amazing explanation on the cause of error! However your solution doesn't seem to work - getting `invalid operands to binary expression` and `static_assert failed due to requirement 'std::__is_invocable<std::less<Tuple> &, const Tuple &, const Tuple &>{}' "comparison object must be invocable with two arguments of key type` errors.

Also a thank you for the aside - I came from C and kept the habit.

Comment: @terrabyte: when I stick the code into [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ao3n6jnWo) it certainly compiles for (I spliced it together into just one translation unit but that shouldn't be the issue). Maybe you defined the `operator<` a member function. If so, you'd want to use something like `bool operator< (Tuplle const& o) const { return this->i < o.i; }`.

Comment: Oh my bad I thought you meant define the operator within the struct itself. This works, had to declare it as static though.